# React/Redux, useEffect/useSelector, stale closures and event listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a React/Redux class component which I'm converting to a functional component.

Previously, it had a `componentDidMount` callback which added an event listener for a custom event dispatched from elsewhere in the app. This is being replaced by `useEffect`. The event listener, on triggering, calls a method elsewhere in this component.

This method performs actions which depend on the values retrieved from a selector. Initially I was passing `useEffect` an empty array of dependencies so it would only add the event listener on mount. However, obviously this results in a stale closure around the selector values. A working solution is to pass it the selector as a dependency – however, this results in the listener being removed/re-added every time the value of the selector changes, which isn't great.

I'm trying to think of a solution which only adds the event listener the one time while allowing the called method to access the current value of the selector.

Example code:

```
const currentValue = useSelector(state => getValue(state));

useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener('my.custom.event', handleEvent);

  return(() => document.removeEventListener('my.custom.event', handleEvent));
}, []);

const handleEvent = () => {
  console.log(currentValue)
}
```

As is, this creates a stale closure around `currentValue` so that on event trigger, the value logged isn't necessarily the most recent.

Changing `[]` to `[currentValue]` in `useEffect` results in the expected behavior, but removes/re-adds the event listener on every change of `currentValue`.

Since this isn't a state value of the component, there's no option to use a callback like `console.log(currentValue => console.log(currentValue))` to access the most recent value. I also played around with using `useRef` to hold onto the value, but I believe I'd need some way to update the ref value every time the selector's value changes, which isn't much of a solution.

In the actual component, the value of `currentValue` is modified in Redux by other components so changing it into a state value isn't really workable either.

I'm wondering:

- whether there's a solution to refreshing the value of the selector in the called method;
- whether the only solution is to remove/re-add the listener on dependency change, or;
- whether it's best to just leave this component as a class component and bypass this issue entirely (`componentDidMount` doesn't suffer from the stale closure issue.)

Comment: You could pass `[currentValue]` dependencies to the `useEffect`.

Comment: *whether the only solution is to remove/re-add the listener on dependency change* - This is fine because the previous listener gets removed by the cleanup function. Only one listener is active at any time, so it shouldn't affect the performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `useRef` method is usually the solution for this problem, but you'll need another `useEffect` to update the ref with the `currentValue`:

```
const currentValue = useSelector(state => getValue(state));
const valueRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => { valueRef.current = currentValue; }, [currentValue]);

useEffect(() => {
  const handleEvent = () => {
    console.log(valueRef.current)
  }

  document.addEventListener('my.custom.event', handleEvent);

  return(() => document.removeEventListener('my.custom.event', handleEvent));
}, []);
```

However, you can also extract the entire function out of the `useEffect`, and use it in a hook, so you can easily create a custom hook for event handling:

```
const useEventHandler = (eventName, eventHandler, eventTarget = document) => {
  const eventHandlerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    eventHandlerRef.current = eventHandler;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleEvent = (...args) => eventHandlerRef?.current(...args);

    eventTarget.addEventListener(eventName, handleEvent);

    return (() => eventTarget.removeEventListener(eventName, handleEvent));
  }, []);
}
```

Using the hook:

```
const currentValue = useSelector(state => getValue(state));

useEventHandler('my.custom.event', () => console.log(currentValue))
```

Comment: Hmm.... this seems like a solution which works, but admittedly also isn't so great, as it requires effectively the same amount of additional work as removing/re-adding the event listener in the first place, namely adding a dependency on selector change.

Extracting the method into its own useEffect hook wouldn't work as the method is being potentially called by another listener in the same component, namely an onClick listener (two different ways to trigger the same effect.)

Comment: The dependency is not a must, you can update the `ref` on each iteration (see the custom hook). In addition, if you have many updates, removing/adding an event listener is costlier than shallow comparison.

Comment: If no other better way comes along, I'll mark this as the answer. However, I'm wondering if there's a good reason why I shouldn't just leave this as a class component rather than refactoring it to be functional.

Comment: > removing/adding an event listener is costlier than shallow comparison.

Perhaps true, though it does also make the code a bit more opaque.

Comment: The standard benefits of hook - shorter, easier to write and read (edge cases like this are a counter argument of-couse), and the fact that the entire React eco system is moving towards hooks, so 3rd parties offer rich hook based solutions. –

Comment: hmm, I have the exact scenario with `react navigation 6.x` listeners, but even this solution gave me the undesired behavior mentioned in this question. But your solution looks really correct and makes total sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

> however, this results in the listener being removed/re-added every time the value of the selector changes, which isn't great.

Why is it a problem? Does it affect performance of your app in any measurable way? From an immutability point of view, if the value change, then the event listener does something different, so it makes sense to simply replace the event listener by a different one.

If the value changes many times a second (for instance at every frame or every mousemove), then it does create a small performance hit, in which case Ori Drori's solution might be a good one, but it makes the code harder to understand and the performance gain is pretty small.

But if the value only changes a few times a second or less often, I would not worry at all about adding and removing the event listener.

Comment: It does frequently change a few times a second. I haven't measured whether there's a performance hit, only observed that this seems sub-optimal and wanted to see whether there was a solution or not.